# UITableViewCell in GroupTableView Style table don't have first and last cell left and right corners round

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9

I have a group tableview with background color set to clear. I am not getting first and last cell left and right corners round. Just wondering what might be an issue?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The corners haven't been round since iOS 7.0 came out.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  Also, can you describe exactly what you're looking for?  You might also consider searching StackOverflow for related questions (or looking on the right), since there are plenty of other questions about table cells with rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show you code but you have to make that happen:

tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;